# how to create a 64bit Ubuntu VM using oracle virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I just downloaded and installed Oracle VM Virtualbox version 4.3.  My host machine is a 64bit Ubuntu box as well, version 14.0.4

I used this page:https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads
and selected the Ubuntu 13.0.4 AMD64 option.

In creating a new VM, I've noticed that I don't have 64bit Ubuntu as an option in the list of Linux machines.

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem some days ago, and the steps that I followed to solve it are the next ones:

1. In your BIOS settings, you have to enable Machine Virtualization or Virtual Machine Support
2. In VirtualBox, Open a New Virtual Machine and go to "Settings -> System -> Acceleration" and activate "Enable VT-x/AMD-V".

Hope it helps

Comment: Also make sure Hyper-V (or any other form of bare-metal hypervisor) is not installed